# Libgdx. Использование ресурсов android и создание сервисов

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-service

Пишу выпускную работу на Java/Android, используя libgdx. Планировал использовать строковые ресурсы android для локализации под разные языки. Оказалось мимо.
Так же думал использовать сервисы android для отсчитывания определённого времени и создания уведомлений (пишу тамагочу). Тут тоже неудача.
По крайней мере ни одного, ни другого я не смог реализовать самостоятельно или найти в интернете.
Возможно ли как либо написать эти идеи?

Comment: Про локализацию можно почитать тут https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Internationalization-and-Localization. А что с сервисами не так? Просто создаешь как обычно.

Comment: @MasterFlomaster Спасибо за ссылку. А на счёт сервисов, их разве надо не в core создавать? Я думал что там, так как доступ к ним получить не получиться, насколько я знаю

Comment: Сервисы создашь в модуле android, а потом можешь просто использовать нужные классы из core

Comment: @MasterFlomaster понятно. Большое спасибо за помощь